# Java - How is it possible to use a method without a Object reference

Tags: java, android, object, methods

I am curious to understand how I am able to call a method without calling it *ON* and object reference.

Here is a method I created:

```
 public void changeAlpha(float f, View v) {
        v.animate().alpha(f).setDuration(5000);
    }
```

Here you can see that inside of the If/elif flow, I am calling `changeAlpha` without calling it on  an object reference. How is that possible?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.dragonImage);


    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (imageView.getAlpha() == 1) {
                changeAlpha(0, imageView);
            } else if (imageView.getAlpha() == 0) {
                changeAlpha(1, imageView);
            }
        }
    });


}
```

Comment: completely unrelated, but your onClick(View v) method only needs one line. **changeAlpha(imageView.getAlpha() ^ 1, imageView);**

Comment: @WalterM - Thanks! But how does the ^ 1 work? What does that do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Java, if you do not explicitly mention an object, there is an implicit `this` added.

This is for example how the `findViewById` method is being called, it is equivalent to `this.findViewById`

Additionally in this case, you have an [anonymous inner class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) (extending View.onClickListener). Inner classes in Java can access the containing classes' methods, which is why you can call changeAlpha where you do. This is actually equivalent to `ContainingClass.this.changeAlpha`. `ContainingClass.this` is the way in Java to reference the instance of the containing class (`this` would only reference the inner class). Again, the reference is implicit without you having to type it and allows access to the changeAlpha method.

Comment: So because this method is within the `if` loop which is referencing the ImageView, the implicit `this` is referencing the view?

Comment: @AdamBen-David I've updated the answer, I didn't notice you are also using an inner class. The implicit reference in this case is actually to the containing class where you have the changeAlpha method. The compiler figures out what the reference should be for you, which is why you don't have to bother adding it yourself

Answer (score 1):

In your example code, you are calling the method from an inner class. In order to this code work you must indicate what Class the the this (implicitly or nor).

Fore example, if the **onCreate** method belongs to MainActivity class, you will call the changeAlpha by typing MainActivity.this.changeAlpha

Comment: is it the full answer?